# Object.callGenericMethod() in java

Tags: java, actionscript-3

Lets say i have these 3 classes

```
class Human
  public void eat()

class Lawyer extends Human
  public void beEvil()

class Murderer extends Human
  public void beEvil()
  public void kill()
```

Now i have a handler for actions, and i want to handle actions without knowing what i am. So for example:

```
handleBeEvil(Human human)
{
    ..
    human.beEvil(); //wont obviously work
    ..
}
```

In as3 for example, i woud use

```
handleBeEvil(Object human)
{
   human.beEvil(); //would pass compiler, work or break runtime
}
```

Whats the best way to accomplish this in Java? I would like to avoid putting all the declerations in the Human class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface and have both `Lawyer` and `Murderer` implement it (i.e. `class Lawyer extends Human implements Evil`):

```
interface Evil {
    void beEvil();
}
```

Then your method would be

```
... handleBeEvil(Evil human)
{
    ..
    human.beEvil();  // now this will work
    ..
}
```

Comment: Was hoping in something faster since i'm migrating code, but i guess i'll do it the right way, thanks.